# trying to make this work not sure why its why

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
# Get the user's starting weight.
weight = input('What is your starting weight? ')

# Display the weight loss table.
for month in range(1, 7):
    weight = -4
    print('At the end of month', month,
          'your weight will be', weight, 'lbs.')
```

Comment: So it's printing `-4` 6 times? What output are you expecting?

Comment: so you are supposed to input any weight then it supposed to subtract 4 each time if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess try changing:

```
    weight = -4
```

To:

```
    weight -= 4
```

Also make the input a string, like this:

```
# Get the user's starting weight.
weight = int(input('What is your starting weight? '))

# Display the weight loss table.
for month in range(1, 7):
    weight -= 4
    print('At the end of month', month,
          'your weight will be', weight, 'lbs.')
```